# How to access data from a survey in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a survey with few questions in it,i have to access data such as questions their options and responses to each question from the survey list.
My requirement is to make a pie chart for each question of the survey based on their responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Excel to build the pie chart using the SharePoint survey list as a data source. You can then deploy the Excel workbook to SharePoint and use Excel Services. Excel Services Web Parts can be added to Web Part pages.

More info on SharePoint list data sources in Excel here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/excel_services__powerpivot_for_sharepoint_support_blog/archive/2013/07/11/excel-services-using-a-sharepoint-list-as-a-data-source.aspx.

PS. If you find info about using the Chart Web Part, it has been discontinued on SP 2013.